# BST Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search-tree

Assume that T is a binary search tree with n nodes and height h. Each node x of T stores a
real number x.Key. Give the worst-case time complexity of the following algorithm Func1(T.root). You
need to justify your answer.

```
Func 1 (x) 
    if (x == NIL) return 0; 
    s1 <- Func1(x.left()); 

    if (s1 < 100) then
       s2 <- Func1(x.Right());
    end
    else
       s2 <- 0; 
    end

    s <- s1 + s2 + x.Key(); 
    return (s);
```

x.left() & x.right() return left and right child of node x
x.key() return the key stored at node x

For the worst case run time, I was thinking that this would be O(height of tree) since this basically act like the minimum() or maximum() binary search tree algorithms.  However, it's recursive, so I'm slightly hesitant to actually write O(h) as the worst case run-time.

When I think about it, the worst case would be if the function executed the if(s1 < 100) statement for every x.left, which would mean that every node is visited, so would that make the run time O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the worst-case runtime of this function is Θ(n), which happens if that if statement always executes. In that case, the recursion visits each node, recursively visits the full right subtree, then recursively visits the full left subtree. (It also does O(1) work per node, which is why this sums up to O(n)).